# Default values in Mongodb 3.6

Tags: mongodb, validation, schema

Is there any way to specify default field values in Mongodb 3.6 in the process of creating a collection with db.createCollection()?

Comment: I think its a new feature yet to be added:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24430

Comment: I think I have to enforce this in the business logic !!

Answer (score 1):

The following are not supported in MongoDB’s implementation of JSON Schema:

The keywords:
$ref,
$schema,
default,
definitions,
format,
id

Yoc can check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#examples

Answer (score -1):

We can specify with enum datatype as below with the support of MongoDB Schema validator - check the default values for Major field below.

```js
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa", "address.city", "address.street" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            gender: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is not required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               minimum: 0,
               description: "must be a double and is required"
            },
            "address.city" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            "address.street" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: That's not a default value. That's just the list of possible values.